# How did so many certificates in my Mac system, why I can't delete them?

Tags: ssl

I've been experiencing a "ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT" when visiting https://angular.io

I haven't solved this problem yet. But how does so many certificates in my Mac and I can't delete them? It is the 1st time I see this part of Mac OS.  How do I delete them?

[image]

Comment: Those are system roots. You don't want to delete them all of them. Doing so would entrust any cert that's been issued by them, which would make HTTPS broken on your system.

Comment: @vcsjones https is kind of broken already on my computer, since I can't visit https://angularjs.io. I've exhausted all the options that I can find on google. Do you know what is going on?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu That site doesn't load over HTTPS for me, either. Also, [a large portion of the internet](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/10/15/globalsign_incident_report/) is having HTTPS problems. GlobalSign accidentally revoked 1000s of certificates last week. It will take time to un-revoke them.

Comment: @vcsjones Thanks for the info! The article mentioned "Tech-savvy netizens hit by the blunder can attempt to clear their revocation list caches and fetch a correction from GlobalSign to fix the problem". Do you know how to do it? Any link that I can learn more about fixing it by myself?